# Surrounding multiple words with tags - ElasticSearch Highlighter in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, highlight

When performing ElasticSearchs query with highlighting, is it possible to surround more than one word with highlighting tags?

For example when I perform query "ajax basics", I get:

```
someText... <a href='#' class='highlightedTerm'>ajax</a> <a href='#' class='highlightedField'>basics</a> someText...
```

And this is what I would like to get:

```
someText... <a href='#' class='highlightedTerm'>ajax basics</a> someText...
```

I am using these settings for highlighter and querying:

```
SearchResponse response = getClient().prepareSearch("user")
    .setTypes("document")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setPostFilter(privacyFilter)
    .setQuery(qb)
    .setFrom(first)
    .setSize(pageSize)
    .setExplain(true)
    //
    // Highlight
    .addHighlightedField("fileName")
    .addHighlightedField("content")
    .setHighlighterOptions(highlighterOptions)
    .setHighlighterPreTags("<a href='#' class='highlightedTerm'>")
    .setHighlighterPostTags("</a>")
    // -------------------------------------
    //
    .addFields("*", "_source")
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

I have tried to remove *space* from boundary characters:

```
Map<String, Object> highlighterOptions = new HashMap<>();
highlighterOptions.put("boundary_chars", "s.,!?\\t\\n");
```

But, the result was the same.

Thanks

Vladimir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I was using **plain highlighter** instead of **fast vector highlighter**. Just adding **fast vector highlighter** solved my problem.

To enable **fast vector highlighter**, I added specific *mapping* for type on which I performed search.

Precisely, i added

```
.field("term_vector", "with_positions_offsets")
```

on the field on which I wanted to perform highlighting.

```
// Create mapping
XContentBuilder xb = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
        .startObject("document")
        // - document
        .startObject("properties")
        // - properties
        //
        .startObject("content")
        .field("type", "string")
        .field("term_vector", "with_positions_offsets")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("contentType")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("fileName")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("fileSize")
        .field("type", "long")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("openable")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("ownerUserId")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("privacy")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        //
        .startObject("searchable")
        .field("type", "string")
        .endObject()
        //
        // - end properties
        .endObject()
        // - end document
        .endObject()
        .endObject();

// Prepare mapping
PutMappingRequestBuilder pmrb = client.admin().indices()
        .preparePutMapping("user")
        .setType("document");

pmrb.setSource(xb);

// Create type and mapping
PutMappingResponse response = pmrb.execute().actionGet();
if (!response.isAcknowledged()) {
    LOG.info("Error while creating mapping for user document.");
} else {
    LOG.info("Mapping created for user document.");
}
```

Some info on that subject: [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html)

Comment: What version of ES were you using? I'm trying this same thing using fvh, but it's surrounding the highlighted words like `<em>foo</em> <em>bar</em>`, instead of `<em>foo bar</em>`. Did you do anything else special in your config?

Comment: Nevermind. Fast-vector-highlighting did work if I was doing a match_phrase query. I guess this is because the highlighter uses the same terms as the ones in the query. It was always treating `foo bar` as `foo` and `bar`, and never as the single entity, when I was doing a simple match query.